# RichFaces 4: jquery effect on rendered component

Tags: jquery, richfaces

Is there a way to properly `fadeIn()` (or any other effect) a fresh-`rendered` component?

For instance:

```
<h:panelGrid id="sampleGrid" columns="2" rendered="#{bean.showGrid}">
     ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

When the above is rendered, I try:

```
jQuery(#{rich:element('sampleGrid')}).hide().fadeIn('fast');
```

Can I achieve the same effect without calling `hide()`?

Things get worse if an action takes place and the component is `rendered="false"`. How to handle then a `fadeOut()` effect? In this case the element is no longer part of the DOM tree, so is it possible at all to demonstrate the effect?

So, to sum up: which is the proper way to have jQuery effects when the render state of a component changes?

Comment: If you're going to apply js effects on a dom element (a div, a table or w/e), don't use the `rendered` attribute in the component, keep it rendered all the time.

Comment: Yes, as far I can see this makes sense, but there are some cases where effects even then cannot be applied properly. For example, when a `<h:graphicImage>` changes its value to an empty image the `fadeOut()` effect is not displayed. In such cases, should I apply the effect before rendering the component?

Comment: The JSF components are plain HTML components in the dom. if an image (img html component) has no value, of course that the fadeOut effect wont be displayed. In your case, I would test the effects on plain html and then use them in JSF components.